# How to create a delay for each item in bee-queue?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made a queue using bee-queue lib but the delayUntil doesn't work

```
     await queue
        .createJob(process)
        .timeout(60 * 1000 * 2)
        .retries(2)
        .backoff('fixed', 60 * 1000)
        .delayUntil(Date.now() + 3000) // The idea is each "process" go to queue each 3 seconds
        .save();
```

Anybody have the same problem? Or exist other way to process each item in the queue with a delay?

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `activateDelayedJobs` property on your queue to `true`. [See the API documentation](https://github.com/bee-queue/bee-queue#settings).

Answer (score -1):

delayUntil in bee queue must be in ISOstring format. you can use moment for this purpose.

```
  const delay =  moment().add(3, 'seconds').toISOString()
  await queue
        .createJob(process)
        .timeout(60 * 1000 * 2)
        .retries(2)
        .backoff('fixed', 60 * 1000)
        .delayUntil(Date.parse(delay)) 
        .save();
```

Comment: Date.parse returns the date in milliseconds, use another lib for this is totally unnecessary.